# OpenCV VideoCapture always fails on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: c++, opencv, raspberry-pi

`VideoCapture.isOpened()` always returns zero whatever the video format is. I can play videos on the RPi but the OpenCV program closes silently without any error. I have the same code running on VS2010  on windows without problems.

- code compiles with no error, reaches the video read point and close
- ffmpeg in 3rdpart  folder is available
- code could read images without the need for the full path

Comment: I suggest you show more of your code.

Comment: it's not my code, even examples that have video can't load it like qt example. 
I need help in OpenCV setup and I hope to so;ve without re-compiling it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used this line to compile and every thing went well!

```
g++ main.cpp -o app $(pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv)
```

I was compiling using cmake with this CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( App )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable( App main.cpp )
target_link_libraries( App${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```